# Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators using $lt

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
filteredListings = await Listing.aggregate([
          { $match: { category: req.params.category } },
          { price: { $lt: 150 } }
        ]);
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get all listings with a field price of less than 150. what is the correct way of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add it in `$and` operator inside the `$match` statement

```
filteredListings = await Listing.aggregate([
  { $match: { $and: [{ category: req.params.category }, { price: { $lt: 150 } }] } }    
]);
```